# Kafka - Dynamic / Arbitrary Partitioning

Tags: asynchronous, apache-kafka, job-scheduling

I'm in the process of building a consumer service for a Kafka topic. Each message contains a url to which my service will make an http request. Each message / url is completely independent from other messages / urls.

The problem I'm worried about is how to handle long-running requests. It's possible for some http requests to take 50+ minutes before a response is returned. During that time, I do not want to hold up any other messages.

What is the best way to parallelize this operation?

I know that Kafka's approach to parallelism is to create partitions. However, from what I've read, it seems that you need to define the number of partitions up front when I really want an infinite or dynamic number of partitions (ideally each message gets its own partition created on the fly)

As an example, let's say I create 1,000 partitions. If 1,001+ messages are produced to my topic, the first 1,000 requests will be made but every message after that will be queued up until the previous request in that partition finishes.

I've thought about making the http requests asynchronous but then I seem to run into a problem when determining what offset to commit.

For instance, on a single partition I can have a consumer read the first message and make an async request. It provides a callback function which commits that offset to Kafka. While that request is waiting, my consumer reads the next message and makes another async request. If that request finishes before the first it will commit that offset. Now, what happens if the first request fails for some reason or my consumer process dies? If I've already committed a higher offset, it sounds like this means my first message will never get reprocessed, which is not what I want.

I'm clearly missing something when it comes to long-running, asynchronous message processing using Kafka. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have thoughts on how to best solve this? Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at Apache Storm for the processing portion of your consumer and leave the message storage and retrieval to Kafka.  What you've described is a very common use case in Big Data (although the 50+ minute thing is a bit extreme).  In short, you'll have a small number of partitions for your topic and let Storm stream processing scale the number of components ("bolts" in Storm-speak) that would actual make the http requests. A single spout (the kind of storm component that reads data from an external source) could read the messages from the Kafka topic and stream them to the processing bolts.

I've posted [an open source example](https://github.com/IntersysConsulting/ingestive) of how to write a Storm/Kafka application on github.

Some follow-on thoughts to this answer:

1) While I think Storm is the correct platform approach to take, there's no reason you couldn't roll your own by writing a Runnable that performs the http call and then write some more code to make a single Kafka consumer read messages and process them with multiply-threaded instances of your runnable.  The management code required is a bit interesting, but probably easier to write than what it takes to learn Storm from scratch.  So you'd scale by adding more instances of the Runnable on more threads.

2) Whether you use Storm or your own multi-threaded solution, you'll still have the problem of how to manage the offset in Kafka.  The short answer there is that you'll have to do your own complex offset management.  Not only will you have to persist the offset of the last message you read from Kafka, but you'll have to persist and manage the list of in-flight messages currently being processed.  In this way, if your app goes down, you know what messages were being processed and you can retrieve and re-process them when you start back up.  The base Kafka offset persistence doesn't support this more complex need, but it's only there as a convenience for the simpler use cases anyway.  You can persist your offsets info anywhere you like (Zookeeper, file system or any data base).

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I have long-term plans to look at stream processing (Storm, Samza, etc.) but this current problem needs a short-term solution given a current deadline. Any thoughts on a hold-over solution?

Comment: Just added those comments